# Spring cache try and cache user

Tags: spring, caching

I am trying to cache the  UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) 
the problem is that after the caching the results comes with the correct user but
the password is always set to null but it was not null when cached

```
@Service
```

public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Cacheable(value="usersLogged" ,key="#username" ,unless="#result.password==null")
@Override
public org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User loadUserByUsername(
        String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    try {
        // User user = userRepository.getUserByEmail(username); Switch to id
        // token base
        User user = userRepository.findOne(username);
        if (user == null) {

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                    "Invalid username/password.");
        }

        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = user.isActive();

        String userN = user.getId(); // the suer is in the system

        String pass = user.getPassword();

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils
                .createAuthorityList(user.getRole().toString());

        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userBuild = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                userN, pass, user.isEnabled(), accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        return userBuild;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
        // throw new
        // UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username/password.");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Seems like spring cache have problems caching when public visibility
password is protected
In the manual 
When using proxies, you should apply the cache annotations only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private or package-visible methods with these annotations, no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the configured caching settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see below) if you need to annotate non-public methods as it changes the bytecode itself

Comment: Any way does anyone knows i way to pass it ?